# Ping MySQL to keep connection alive in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, rabbitmq

I have a bunch of workers waiting for tasks (using Django as ORM). My problem is that if there's no task for a given amount of time (whatever MySQL wait_timeout variable is set to) the MySQL connection times out and hence the worker dies.

My first approach to solve this problem was simply to increase the wait_timeout to a higher integer, but I thought a better solution might be to ping MySQL like every 30mins or so if there has been no task to keep the connection alive.

So my question is; how can I using the Django ORM simply ping MySQL to keep the connection alive? What's the best practice here, just do a simple stupid query ?

Comment: Why exactly u would like to keep that connection? U should rather just improve workers to connect whenever they will have something to do.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html

Comment: @ProblemFactory Good point.. do you have any pseudo code to do that with Django ?

Comment: Check my answer, if u show us ur current worker code I would improve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django actually handles the database connection (and reconnection of an expired one) automatically.

The problem here was that I'm handling the database transactions manually in one of my workers (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually), and apparently, that forces you to handle the whole database connection yourself as well.

Answer (score 2):

Setup a connection pool or manually connect the worker as suggested by @ProblemFactory

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html

Comment: This is not related to Django, but to MySQL and Python independently

Answer (score 2):

connection.connection.ping() will work only with Oracle and MySQL, do not use it.

Right solution is:

```
from django.db import connection  # works with default connection only, use 'connections'

if connection.is_usable():
    print("ok")
else:
    print("error")
```

Comment: I had `connection is None` condition (at `is_usable()` MySQL internals) so `is_usable` raised an exception, so need to wrap in a `try:`

Answer (score 2):

I've met the same problem with you , and solve it by following code:

```py
from django.db import connection
connection.close()
```

And [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/21597#comment:29) is the discussion of this problem from Django.

I'll paste that explanation here:

> RECOMMENDED SOLUTION: close the connection with `from django.db import connection; connection.close()` when you know that your program is going to be idle for a long time.

So I think you don't have to ping MySQL to keep the connection alive, but you should close the connection when worker thread will be idle for a long time (like waiting tasks), because everytime you do the query, django will establish a connection for you, but it won't close the connection when worker thread waiting or doing something without db query.

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.db import connection

connection.connection.ping()
```

Answer (score 0):

Better idea is just to connect to ur database when it is needed! Especially that u mentioned about intervals like 30mins.

```
while true:
   sleep(X)
   if some_task:
      connect_to_DB()
      do_something()
```

Comment: The problem is that I can't predict when the tasks arrive, at some hour there could be none, in the next there could be 1,000,000 tasks.. so hence I would not like to reconnect for every task

Comment: Of course not, u should define `task` as a whole job to do, not one query.

Comment: Even though one task is defined as one whole job to do, the job itself in my use case is very small, and there are tons of them.. It would be stupid of me to reconnect for every task even with this definition